# Maven - Unknow Proxy

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

> Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.3.1 or one of
>   its dependencies could not be  resolved: Failed to read artifact
>   descriptor for
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:jar:2.3.1:  Could not
>   transfer artifact
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:pom:2.3.1 from/to
>   snapshots 
>   `(http://160.50.40.30:8080/sub-app/content/repositories/snapshots)`:
>   Connection to  `http://160.50.40.30:8080` refused: Connection timed
>   out -> [Help 1]

I have a complete build(build sub porjects and after main) shell script(build_app.sh). I am running from terminal.

I am getting above error. But I did not specify anywhere this url(`http://160.50.40.30:8080`).

I don't have any customization settings in my apache-maven-3.0.5 folder.

I did not specify in any pom.

I tried with apache-maven-3.0.4 also, but I got the same error.

Comment: I would assume you have a user specific configuration in `$HOME/.m2/settings.xml` which should define the repositories.

Comment: i don't have any personal settings.

Comment: Is Maven left original and not changed the configuration in **MAVEN_HOME/conf/settings.xml**

Comment: the existing apache-maven-3.0.5 folder renamed as apache-maven-3.0.5_old folder. and get the latest from the apache-maven-3.0.5.tar.gz

Comment: Can you show your full pom, cause otherwise it's not really possible to help.